# How to Overriding Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select.php in Magento

Tags: javascript, php, magento, overriding, magento-1.9

I am new user of Magento (in customization). I want to override Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select.php file in local folder. Till I am doing overriding functionality.

Please can any one suggest me which steps should I follow for override this file. And for overriding which other files need to add in local folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two way to do it

1. if you  want to just override block then copy that file from core to your local folder, please maintain the same folder structure as core.
2. second way I think this is the bese way to do it by creating an extension you can get more details from here

http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/

Let me know if you have any query

Thanks

Comment: As per first method I copy the Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select.php this file in local folder EM_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select.php at same path just in EM folder and created config.xml in etc folder of module then it showing an error 'Fatal error: Call to a member function addToChildGroup() on a non-object in D:\wamp\www\magento_new_pro\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php on line 815' It means other folder and files in Block folder also need to copy..I get confused. because I am trying overriding from last couple of day

Comment: you are doing wrong dear, if follow first step then there  is no need to create config.xml just follow app/code/local/Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select.php you need to change EM to Mage that's all

Comment: I am keeping Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select.php this file at location D:\wamp\www\magento_new_pro\app\code\local\EM\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type. It is in EM folder so instead of Mage replace the EM and in select.php doing one chage i.e. class EM_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select..

Comment: could you please clear me you want to create an extension or just override block file ? if you just want to override block file then there is not need to create  Em folder structure. just copy from core folder and place in your local folder with exactly core folder structure as i mention in the above thread. if you need more help skype : nickkartara